# How to access my JFrame on EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have a class on which it hold a JFrame, and on my JFrame, it contains some methods that i would want to call. The problem is that my class is in the main thread and mFrame is now delegated to the EDT thread, so how do i sent instructions to EDT to run those methods?

Update:

This is my FrameRadar that extends JFrame, as you see i have a update method, basically there is also a update on mDisplay and mRadar, those are jpanel.

```
FrameRadar Class ...(

public class FrameRadar{
...
public void update() {
    mAccessor.getmDisplay().update();
    mAccessor.getmRadar().update();
}
```

This is my MainRadar class, it contains a FrameRadar on which i also have a update method. That update method will call jframe's update.

```
class MainRadar(
 ....
private FrameRadar mFrame;
 ....
public StateMainGame() {
    init();
}

public void init() {
....
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mFrame = new FrameRadar();
            mFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
....
public void update() {
    mFrame.update();
}
```

So as you see, MainRadar.Update-> FrameRadar->Update-> Jpanels->Update. The problem is that i cannot use

> mFrame.update();

Comment: Please share a sample code. Its not clear.

Comment: Why can't you use `mFrame.update()`? If this should be done on the EDT, you may wrap this call into a new `Runnable`, like you already did it for the construction....

Comment: Why you can't call `mFrame.update()`? Is it not updating your `JFrame`?

Comment: No, it is not updating. i am getting a nullpointerexecption error. The first one in the list is  mFrame.update().

Comment: Wouldn't new Runnable created a new thread?